# Can the elliptical slice sampler be used to infer kernel hyperparameters for GP Regression?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-process, slice-sampler

## Context

Suppose I have some sample points $X$, and responses, $\mathbf{y}$. I wish infer the mechanism by which $\mathbf{y}$ is generated from $X$ using a Gaussian Process (GP) as a prior distribution, i.e., I assume $\mathbf{y}$ can be modelled as a draw from a GP:

$p(\mathbf{y}|X, \theta) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}; m(X), K(X, X | \theta))$

where $m$ is a function describing the prior mean, $k$ is a covariance kernel which designates the covariance between each of the points in $X$, and $\theta$ is a vector of hyperparameters which tune the behaviour of the kernel.

Supposing I fix (choose) $m$ and $k$, I am required to infer suitable values of the hyperparameters, $\theta$, given the likelihood function defined above and the data. In other words, this is a canonical GP regression problem.

One way of doing this is via Markov-Chain Monte-Carlo, in which case we sample from something that is (hopefully) proportional to:

$p(\theta | X, \mathbf{y}) \propto p(\mathbf{y} | X, \theta) p(\theta)$

Which can be accomplished using (for example) Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo (HMC). I'll add for reference that I've had no (relevant) issues implementing or using HMC to accomplish the above.

## Question

One alternative to HMC I have seen mentioned for performing MCMC for GP models is [Murray *et. al.*'s elliptical slice sampler](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/murray10a/murray10a.pdf) (ESS), though after studying the paper I am a little unsure how the algorithm might be used to sample the kernel hyperparameters, $\theta$.

In particular, if I look at open source implementations (such as the python version [here](https://github.com/jobovy/bovy_mcmc/blob/master/bovy_mcmc/elliptical_slice.py)), the algorithm appears to accept and propose parameter vectors of dimension equivalent to the latent function one assumes is Gaussian distributed: that is, the algorithm appears to propose latent functions drawn from a fixed covariance matrix, and *not* samples of the kernel hyperparameters.

**Is it possible to use ESS to sample kernel hyperparameters for the type of canonical GP regression problems described above (presumably via extra operations after sampling the latent function), or do I misunderstand the purpose of the algorithm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: see [Slice sampling covariance hyperparameters
of latent Gaussian models by Murray and Adams (2010)](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2010/file/4d5b995358e7798bc7e9d9db83c612a5-Paper.pdf). They use ESS as a step in their MCMC algorithm.

*[Clarification after comment:]*

Well, yes and no. The ESS is used as a step to sample the latent $f$ vector given the hyperparameters $\theta$, while their paper actually develops a new **(non-elliptical!)** slice sampler for updating covariance hyperparameters. So the ESS is just an auxiliary step.

That being said, I have used ESS with success for GP regression problems that have unbounded hyperparameters; simply transform them to $N(0,I)$ using some sequence of bijectors. Then ESS can be used in principle. But this does not guarantee success, since "any distribution [on the reals] can be factored [that way]" [(Murray+ 2010)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0175).

Comment: Is ESS not used to sample the *latent* function (the author's "$f$") here, rather than the kernel hyperparameters? 

ESS seems (as I currently understand it) to be used to draw sample paths *from* the GP as part of a larger (hierarchical) model rather than to infer the (kernel) parameters *of* the GP itself, though it's very possible I'm misunderstanding. 

Perhaps need to take a look at the supplied code. Either way this is a helpful reference: appreciated!

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to clarify this point. By the way, [this](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/imurray2/pub/14gess/) could also be interesting.